# May one learn how to breathe from the diaphragm (Buddha Belly Breathing) holistically throughout all of their activities and if so how exactly?

Tags: practice, pranayama

Peace, Divine Love, and Blessings to All.  I recently began to research meditative/breathing for the Solar Plexus.  I was instructed that the "normal breathing" done in the west is not the right/true way that we are supposed to be breathing but instead we should do it from the diaphragm (liken unto babies).  During my research, I came across [Belly Breathing/Diaphragmatic Breathing](https://my.clevelandclinic.org/health/articles/9445-diaphragmatic-breathing) which I came to find out is "Buddha Belly Breathing" (please forgive me if I come across as ignorant not knowing the true terminology and cultural linguistics).

The very little I have done so far has been amazing but extremely difficult.  Inhaling while expanding the stomach (and vice versa) took a lot of concentration while simultaneously trying to keep an erect posture with square shoulders (all while trying to be loose) was/is full of challenges. It made me consider and realize, one how bad my posture is (sad face) and two is it possible to continuously and consistently do this form of breathing throughout the entire day and in all activities?  I understand that meditation is about going inwardly, so I know I must take that journey and do the inner work but I pose this question asking if there are people who have done it, are doing it, and would they kindly share any pointers or guidance about their accomplishment(s).
This question is open to anyone. Feel free to share howsoever you are led to...Thank you.

["This question was originally asked on the Buddhism StackExchange but it was brought to my attention that it would be better suited to propose the question here"](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/44853/21076)

Comment: I will suggest you to read the book 'zenyoga' by dr. PJ seher. But this question is not related to hinduism. Please ask in buddhism stack exchange

Comment: @Rudra Peace and Blessings. Thank you for the book recommendation..... Also if you click the link I posted where I wrote "this question was originally asked on the Buddhism StackExchange" you will see that I asked this question first over there (Buddhism StackExchange) and then was told that it is not related to Buddhism and to ask the question in the Hinduism StackExchange

Comment: I see now. Actually in that book, there is given three step breathing technique. First step is about focusing on taking breathe from belly naturally by practicing a simple method for six months. It will surely help.

Comment: I see now. Actually in that book, there is given three step breathing technique. First step is about focusing on taking breathe from belly naturally by practicing a simple method for six months. It will surely help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to practice it is - lie down flat on your back on the ground, with your face and chest facing skywards. Whenever you take a deep breath in this position, it will involve the belly and somewhat ignore the lungs. Remember what all remains stagnant and what keeps moving.

Next, get up and sit in the Lotus pose and try repeating the same breath -- straight into the belly and largely ignoring the lungs. Release the breath slowly.[a.k.a. Yogic Breathing](https://www.yogapedia.com/definition/7531/deep-breathing)

PS: I keep doing it almost all the time.